# Detecting if a peer is using TCP keepalives (Windows)

Tags: windows, sockets, tcp, keep-alive

is it possible to figure out, or be notified if a peer to whom you are connected is using TCP keepalives?

Furthermore to be notified when a keepalive is sent?

Without resorting to packet-level filtering in a kernel driver?

We have a plug proxy, and a customer wishes client keepalives to be forwarded to the server.  At the moment our best option I think is just to allow setting keepalives on the server-side connection, but I wanted to check if anyone knew a way to detect what the client behaviour was so that relaying of keepalives could be more closely approximated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it possible to figure out, or be notified if a peer to whom you are connected is using TCP keepalives?

No. TCP keepalive doesn't use a protocol extension. It just uses the existing protocol in a specific way so as to provoke a response.

> Furthermore to be notified when a keepalive is sent?

No. A TCP keepalive segment cannot be identified as such.

> Without resorting to packet-level filtering in a kernel driver?

Not even if you do.

> We have a plug proxy, and a customer wishes client keepalives to be forwarded to the server.

Your customer is misinformed.

> At the moment our best option I think is just to allow setting keepalives on the server-side connection

Correct.

> but I wanted to check if anyone knew a way to detect what the client behaviour was so that relaying of keepalives could be more closely approximated.

Not possible.

Comment: Basically the conclusion I arrived at.  However I believe it should be possible at packet level if tracking sequence numbers to identify an empty ACK with the sequence number indicating a keepalive (SEG.SEQ =            SND.NXT-1).  But I'm not going to do that.  Thanks!

Comment: @Adrien The problem with that is that the sending TCP can do that any time it likes, not just for keepalive purposes. It isn't likely to, but it can. That's what I meant by 'no protocol extension'.

Comment: understood, although I can only think of 1 purpose for that and it would be as a keepalive :) - the distinction may not matter in the end.